# Does ZSH's time command take any arguments like -p?

Tags: performance, zsh, timing

I recently installed the developer beta of macOS 10.15 Catalina, which defaults to ZSH instead of BASH.

I have `time` installed as a binary in `/usr/bin/time`, and use that to time some of my scripts. ZSH, however, has this as a built-in command. **My problem is that I usually use `time -p` to format its output in a way I prefer, but that doesn't seem to be possible on ZSH.**

According to `man time`:

> ```
>      -p      The output is formatted as specified by IEEE Std 1003.2-1992 (``POSIX.2'').
> ```

This doesn't seem to apply to ZSH's built-in, and ZSH doesn't seem to be using my installed `time` binary:

#### BASH

```sh
bash-5.0$ which time
/usr/bin/time
bash-5.0$ time echo hello; echo $?
hello

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
0
bash-5.0$ time -p echo hello; echo $?
hello
real 0.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
0
```

#### ZSH

```
is-mbp-bleggiero% which time
time: shell reserved word
is-mbp-bleggiero% time echo hello; echo $?
hello
0
is-mbp-bleggiero% time -p echo hello; echo $?
zsh: command not found: -p
-p echo hello  0.00s user 0.00s system 74% cpu 0.001 total
127
```

And that looks odd to me; it seems to be including the info I want (user vs system & total, formatted as seconds), but it also doesn't run the command, instead complaining that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `/usr/bin/time -p` if you want to use this option, or `=time -p`

The zsh builtin time doesn't take any option (`man zshmisc`).

But you can `export TIMEFMT` with the format you want, including newlines with `\n`.

`echo $TIMEFMT` to see what it is now

Comment: So here's a sub-problem. `echo $TIMEFMT` prints `%J  %U user %S system %P cpu %*E total`, but `time echo hello` just prints `hello`, without any timings. What's going on there?

Comment: You have to call an external program I guess, not a shell function or built-in (`echo` is a built-in).

Comment: I see; `time man man` did print the proper timings. It didn't open the manual page, though, so I guess I'll just always use `=time` because this ZSH `time` builtin seems to never behave as I need